# How can I pass a lambda/std::function/Functor to a variadic function

Tags: c++, lambda, variadic-templates

I have a variadic function like this:

```cpp
template <class... PickComponents, size_t... PickComponentIndices>
void iterateEntitiesInternal(
  const std::function<void(Entity, const PickComponents &...)> &iterFn,
  std::index_sequence<PickComponentIndices...> sequence
);

template <class... PickComponents>
void iterateEntities(const std::function<void(Entity, const PickComponents &...)> &iterFn) {
  iterateEntitiesInternal(iterFn, std::index_sequence_for<PickComponents...>{});
}
```

I want to be able to call the function like this:

```cpp
iterateEntities<A, B, C>([](Entity entity, const auto &c1, const auto &c2, const auto &c3) {
  // ...
});
```

Is there a way I can make this work? I tried creating a template structure like:

```cpp
template <typename T> struct IterFnType { typedef T type; };
```

and using it like this:

```cpp
template <class... PickComponents>
void iterateEntities(const typename IterFnType<std::function<void(Entity, const PickComponents &...)>>::type &iterFn);
```

But it gives me a compiler error in GCC:

> error: ‘typename liquid::EntityStorageSparseSet::IterFnType’ names ‘template<class ... ComponentTypes> template struct liquid::EntityStorageSparseSet::IterFnType’, which is not a type

What is the correct way of passing lambdas to variadic functions?

Comment: Works fine: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/14G9fdj9K

Comment: Are you missing a `template` keyword?

Comment: Reproducing your issue seems to be difficult.  Can you [edit] this question to replace the code snippets with a [mre]?

Comment: I added the class based on my codebase and it is giving me the error: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8hM5KEeMs

Comment: Yes, you're missing `template` in `typename Storage::template IterFnType<...>`. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/cMzozK7oM

Comment: @ecatmur Looks like you could make that into an answer.